# Laravel 5.8 Validation - always bail on any rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Is there any possibility to set `FormRequest` rules to default use `bail` rule without typing in it?

Instead of:

```php
class StoreRequest extends FormRequest {
    function rules() {
        return [
            'name' => 'bail|required|min:3',
            'last_name' => 'bail|required|min:3',
            'names' => 'bail|required|min:3',
            'email' => 'bail|required|email',
            'type' => 'integer|min:10|max:50',
            // [...]
        ];
    }
}
```

I would like to get more cleaner version, like:

```php
class StoreRequest extends FormRequest {

    protected $stopsOnFirstError = true; // I can't find anything like this

    function rules() {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'names' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'type' => 'integer|min:10|max:50',
            // [...]
        ];
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Some of my rules are defined as array:

```php
'type' => [
    'bail',
    'required',
    'integer',
    Rule::in(ContactType::getValues()),
],
```

Comment: I believe that would require overriding the existing validator functions.

Comment: `bail` is already implicit with the `required` rule so it is not necessary. However `bail` will not work in preventing other fields from validating it only stops the other validation rules on the one field it's validating.

Comment: This is what I trying to achieve - stop other validations when first fails. I also have not required fields but validated when present: `bail|integer|min:10'.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Without making it more complex use string replacement

```
<?php
$rules = [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'names' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ];
$stopsOnFirstError = true;
if(stopsOnFirstError){
  array_walk($rules, function(&$value, $key) { $value = 'bail|'.$value; } );
}

print_r($rules);
?>
```

Live Demo : [Link](https://eval.in/1084734)

Output :

```
Array
(
    [name] => bail|required|min:3
    [last_name] => bail|required|min:3
    [names] => bail|required|min:3
    [email] => bail|required|email
)
```

**2)** You can also do this in other way , by just adding `'*' => 'bail',` to apply for all fields

```
class StoreRequest extends FormRequest {
    function rules() {
        return [
            '*' => 'bail',
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'names' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach

Comment: Nice idea, but I've some rules defined as array with closures or `Rule::in` method. I'm updated my question.

Comment: @Daniel:  so will not work with `'*' => 'bail',` ? did you try this ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut: I just checked, unfortunately it not works.

Comment: Pretty simple approach. The idea seems interesting. Would be nice if Laravel came with an option like that by default

Answer (score 1):

You can always override the `validator` method in your form request class:

```
class StoreRequest extends FormRequest {

    private function prependBailOnRule($rule) {
        if (is_string($rule)) {
            return "bail|".$rule;
        } else if (is_array($rule)) {
           return array_merge([ "bail" ], $rule);
        }
    }

    //Adapted from FromRequest::createDefaultValidator
    public function validator(ValidationFactory $factory) {
        return $factory->make(
             $this->validationData(), 
             array_map([$this, 'prependBailOnRule' ], $this->container->call([$this, 'rules'])),
             $this->messages(), $this->attributes()
        );
    }

    function rules() {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'names' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'type' => 'integer|min:10|max:50',
            // [...]
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm using Laravel 8 and easily stop the validating on the first error by setting the $stopOnFirstFailure = true;

```
class StoreRequest extends FormRequest{
protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'      => 'required|min:3',
        'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'names'     => 'required|min:3',
        'email'     => 'required|email',
    ];
}
```

}